How to Edit Template-Based Emails With Locked HTML
I have encountered challenges with template-based emails versus HTML-based emails. Here’s the issue:
When I use a template-based email in SFMC, the HTML is locked, shown by a lock icon next to the HTML code. This locked status restricts me from making direct edits to the HTML or CSS, which complicates quick adjustments, especially when updating styles in the  section.
If I create an HTML-based email, I have more control over the code and can edit the CSS freely. However, this setup lacks drag-and-drop functionality, making it less user-friendly for marketers who are not familiar with HTML and CSS.
Currently, whenever I update a template that multiple emails are using, I need to manually open each email and click "Update Email Now." This action not only adds the latest template content but also introduces unwanted elements from the template into the emails, creating clutter and requiring additional cleanup.
Is there a better way to:
Use a template-based email without locked HTML or have a method to unlock the HTML?
Edit the CSS in the  section more efficiently without triggering unnecessary updates or adding unwanted content?
Any suggestions for improving this process or alternative workflows in SFMC that balance both marketer-friendly functionality and efficient email updates would be greatly appreciated!

I would like to share a workaround for this, which you can consider alongside your current options:

Create a Code Snippet Content Block: Place your existing template code within this content block, then get the ID (E.g. Id is 12345)

Create a blank template. Replace the content with the following code:


<div data-type="slot" data-key="init" data-label="custom-block"></div>
<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking"/>

This template allows emails to leverage drag-and-drop functionality.

Create a Template-Based Email: Use the template created above to make a new email. Drag a code snippet block to the top of the email and insert this code to reference the content block from step 1:

%%=ContentBlockbyID("12345")=%%

Now, whenever you want to update the CSS, you only need to edit the code snippet content block created in step 1. You won't have to click "Update Email Now" or reconfigure elements, as AMPscript retrieves the template content, including CSS, dynamically.
The downsides of this workaround:

You can only fully preview changes by switching to the "Preview and Test" tab.
It may cause confusion when you have other components in the email template since it only appears in the "Preview and Test" mode.


Thank you for the response. Is there any way to have drag-and-drop functionality and the ability to edit the head section in the email without using this workaround?

@teddy23 Not from what I know. Both approaches have their trade-offs. In my experience, I would go with the "old-fashioned" method when working with marketers, while I try to develop a standard template that can be reused across multiple emails :)
